# VLOOKUP, multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

1. I have a tab that has 2 cells which list a room number and start time for a class. In this same tab I am performing a VLOOKUP formula.

`=VLOOKUP(A12&B3,'Fall 2018 export - TEST'!AF2:AF4,1)`

Here A12 is a class room name, and B3 contains the start time.

2. The array ('Fall 2018 export - TEST'!AF2:AF4,1) for the VLOOKUP comes from a different tab and contains multiple text. Each cell in the array looks like this but with different numbers and start times.

   `B8007-1, WJW 326,Class Length: 1.30 hrs. Start Time: 9:00 AM`

   Also, the cell above is a formula:

   `=IF(AE2<>0,CONCATENATE($C2,"-",$E2,", ",$AE2,",","Class Length: ",TEXT($W2,"h.mm")&" hrs.", " Start Time: ", TEXT($S2,"h:mm AM/PM")),0)`
3. The issue I'm having is, every time I try the VLOOKUP formula, it gives me the wrong data.

For example: using this formula

```
  =VLOOKUP(A12&B3,'Fall 2018 export - TEST'!AF2:AF4,1)
```

[with A12 & B3 values as 'WJW 100' and '9:00 AM"]

gives me this

> "B8007-3, WJW 100, Class Length: 1.30 hrs. Start Time: 12:30 PM"

In other words -- it doesn't give me the cell with the correct start time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
 =VLOOKUP("*" & A12 & "*" & TEXT(B3,"h:mm AM/PM") & "*",'Fall 2018 export - TEST'!AF2:AF4,1,False)
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your formula and got an "#N/A" in the cell.

Comment: @Greg please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.